# ADB not recognizing nexus 4 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, adb

I have installed the mtpfs tools for Ubuntu and mounted the nexus 4 successfully. Here the steps:

```
 sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
 sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

added to the file `51-android.rules`:

```
 #LG – Nexus 4
 SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"
```

then

```
 sudo chmod +x /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
 sudo service udev restart
 sudo mkdir /media/nexus4
 chmod 755 /media/nexus4
 sudo mtpfs -o allow_other /media/nexus4
```

Got everything from this site [here](http://www.android.gs/mount-google-nexus-4-mtp-sd-card-on-ubuntu-and-other-linux-computers/).
But unfortunately I can't list the Nexus 4 with `adb`, when I run `adb devices` I get

```
 adb devices
 List of devices attached
```

But no devices are listed...
Do I need to configure anything when I want to access the nexus with adb?

Comment: Have you replaced the "pretty" unicode double quote characters with the regular ones after copying the udev rules from the website? the line should be `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"`

Comment: yes I did, and even changed it to mine according the output of `lsusb`: `Bus 002 Device 004: ID 18d1:4ee1 Google Inc.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try developer options on the device (Nexus 4) and then use "adb devices".

How to enabled developer options? : http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-4/258607-how-close-turn-off-developer-option-my-nexus-4-a.html

So, you should try:

1. Enable the developer option on Nexus 4 (using above link).
2. On terminal, use command "adb kill-server"
3. On terminal, use command "adb start-server"
4. On terminal, use command "adb devices"

You should then be able to see in the device list.

Comment: I already have the options enabled, do I need to set any specific parameters in the options?

Comment: this worked only after I ran adb start-server as root, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

worked for me only when I executed adb commands as root,

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```

Comment: should be the accepted answer. the other one is just dummy.